# Proving Variants of the Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I want to prove that the following variants of the Axiom of Choice are equivalent:

> AC1. Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let
>   $F:X\rightarrow\wp\left(Y\right)-\left\{ \emptyset\right\}$  be a
>   function, where $\wp\left(Y\right)$ is the power set of $Y$. Then
>   there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ such that
>   $f\left(x\right)\in F\left(x\right)$ for all $x\in X$.

and

> AC2. If $X$ is a non-empty set, then there exists a function
>   $f:X\rightarrow\bigcup X$ such that $f\left(A\right)\in A$ for all $A\in X$.

I have proven that AC2 implies AC1 but I am having trouble proving that AC1 implies AC2. I know that I have to chose an appropriate  $Y$ and $F$, but I don't know which ones.

Comment: What do you mean by $\bigcup X$?

Comment: The union of the elements of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $Y$ to be $\bigcup X$, and $F$ to be the identity function. Then apply AC1 to deduce AC2.